# C++, OpenCv: Member function not updating member variables

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers, reference, mat

I have a class MainWindow which contains the function saveImageFile(). This reads an image, puts it into a Canvas object, a class which stores a list of Layer objects, each Layer containing two OpenCv Mats, a pre-effects Mat and a post-effects Mat.

In saveImageFile(), I apply the image effect lumaToAlpha() on layer[1] of the canvas. lumaToAlpha() takes the Layer's pre-effects Mat, performs an operation on it, and stores it in the Layer's post-effects Mat. The function is tested. It works.

However, when I attempt to get the post-effect Mat, I get the original Mat. This is as if lumaToAlpha() did nothing at all, or was performed on a totally different layer object.

I believe this may have something to do with pointers, but I am not confident. What is going wrong?

MainWindow class...

```
//member variables of MainWindow...
Canvas mCanvas;    

void MainWindow::saveImageFile()
{

    Mat mat = imread("C://picture.jpg), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    mCanvas.startCanvas(mat, Canvas::BGRA);

    mCanvas.getLayer(1).lumaToAlpha();
    Mat canvasMat = mCanvas.getLayer(1).getPostEffectMat();
    imwrite("C://picture-result.png", canvasMat);
    //getPostEffectMat is returning the wrong mat!

}
```

Canvas class...

```
//member variables of Canvas...
enum CanvasColorMode { GREY, BGRA };
CanvasColorMode mCanvasColorMode;
QList<Layer> mLayerSet;

Canvas::Canvas()
{
    //empty constructor
}

Layer Canvas::getLayer(int index)
{
    if(0 <= index && index < mLayerSet.size()){
        return mLayerSet.at(index);
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument("layer index not in range");
}

void Canvas::startCanvas(Mat base, CanvasColorMode mode)
{
    mLayerSet.clear();

    if (base.channels() == 1 && mode == Canvas::BGRA){
        cvtColor(base, base, CV_GRAY2BGRA);
    } else if (base.channels() > 1 && mode == Canvas::GREY){
        cvtColor(base, base, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
    }

    Layer layer00(makeCheckMat(base.rows, base.cols, mode));
    Layer layer01(base);

    mLayerSet.append(layer00);
    mLayerSet.append(layer01);
}
```

Layer class...

```
//layer member variables
Mat mPreEffectMat;
Mat mPostEffectMat; 

Layer::Layer(Mat matPrePost)
{
    mPreEffectMat = matPrePost;
    mPostEffectMat = matPrePost;
}

Mat Layer::getPreEffectMat()
{
    return mPreEffectMat;
}

Mat Layer::getPostEffectMat()
{
    return mPostEffectMat;
}

void Layer::setPreEffectMat(Mat mat)
{
    mPreEffectMat = mat;

}

void Layer::setPostEffectMat(Mat mat)
{
    mPostEffectMat = mat;
    qDebug() << "setPostEffectMat";
}

void Layer::lumaToAlpha()
{
    Mat pre = getPreEffectMat();
    Mat post= Mat(pre.rows, pre.cols, CV_8UC4, Scalar::all(0) );

    //SNIP: converts luminence channel to alpha, function tested
    //this works exactly how I expect it to. The question is why
    //is the change not reflected in post mat

    setPostEffectMat(post);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you have a member variable named `mat`. You were hoping to set its value in the function. However, what you have done in the function is define a function local variable. The member variable of the same name is not affected by what you do in the function.

Change the line

```
// This defines a function local variable.
Mat mat = imread("C://picture.jpg), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

to

```
// This sets the value of the member variable.
mat = imread("C://picture.jpg), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```